# Checkbox state always stay checked

Tags: android, checkbox

If I open the activity, the checkbox always stay checked and even if I unchecked it and leave the activity or closed the app it'll stay checked again after restarting the activity.

I've tried saving the state of the activity using the below code snippet.

```
checkBox1.setChecked(getSharedPreferences("NSUK", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("checkBox1", true));

        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                getSharedPreferences("NSUK", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("checkBox", isChecked).apply();

            }
        });
```

The checkbox is expected to always be in the state that the user leave it (checked or unchecked).

Comment: set checked = true

Comment: Can you confirm if `getSharedPreferences(...).getBoolean(...);` is returning the correct value by logging it out?

Comment: Make sure that the check value is actually being saved to and loaded from SharedPreferences

Comment: You are using "checkBox1" to read and "checkBox" to write to preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct but you are storing and getting data form different values.
You are storing in checkBox1 and reading from checkBox. Try with this

```
checkBox1.setChecked(getSharedPreferences("NSUK", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("checkBox", true));

        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                getSharedPreferences("NSUK", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("checkBox", isChecked).apply();

            }
        });
```